# Use batch command to extend display after specific program closes

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that starts Microsoft Flight Simulator X, and upon startup, switches the view mode from extend to main display. **That is the part I have gotten to work.** But upon exit of FSX, I want the view mode to switch back to extend. Running into trouble there. So far, I have tried the `\wait` command, but that did not work. Right now I am trying `if((get-process`, as I read that the batch file would need to monitor if FSX is running or closed in order to move on, but I have not gotten that to work either. Very new at this, so I don't think I'm understanding how the commands work together. The full code is below. What do I need to change?

```
@echo off 
DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
Start "" "A:\Steam\steamapps\common\FSX\fsx.exe" 
Start "" "C:\Users\hamha\Desktop\FSISERVER - Shortcut"
Start "" "C:\Users\hamha\Documents\aismv120\AISmooth.exe"
Taskkill "" "FSISERVER"
Taskkill "" "AISmooth.exe"
if((get-process $fsx.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null){
Start-Process -FilePath "DisplaySwitch.exe /extend"
}
pause
```

Comment: You can make a Powershell/Batch hybrid, but not like that.

Comment: I use `tasklist /fi "imagename eq myprogram.exe" | findstr "some 'correct' string" && goto my program_done` in a "endless" goto loop. I'm on a mac so couldn't check for syntax/check what tasklist outputs for matching process. If more clarification is needed it can be provided on monday.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to simplify this, because I don't have all of the applications you're wanting to run...but you'll get the idea:

```
# Run DisplaySwitch with your arguments
Start-Process 'DisplaySwitch.exe' -ArgumentList '/internal'

# Start your Simulator, and stop your other processes
Start-Process 'Notepad.exe'
Get-Process 'Microsoft.Photos' | Stop-Process -Force

# test that the application is in the process list, then sleep for 1 second, then test again
while(Get-Process 'Notepad' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# Application isn't in the process list, so run your exit code
Start-Process 'DisplaySwitch.exe' -ArgumentList '/extend'
```

A **While Loop** is your friend there.

Now, I'm not sure why you were wanting to do this in a batch file.  If it is just for ease of launch, you can create a shortcut to PowerShell.exe with an argument of the script path, and it should launch (as long as your ExecutionPolicy is set correctly).  If you have any questions about that, let me know.